# Match on a pair of equal values

Tags: scala, tuples, match

I am trying to process a tuple, where one of the cases is that the two values are equal. Is there a better, more concise way to `match` on this than

```
(p, q) match {
  case (p, q) if (p == q) => println("Match!")
  ...
}
```

?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Personally, I think the way you've done it is great because it's simple, intuitive, and clear to the reader what's going on.

That said, here's one way you could do it without an `if` clause.  You could just match on the swapped version, using backticks to turn `q` into stable identifiers.  As @Luigi pointed out, you can just check that `p` matches `q`:

```
  (p, q) match {
    case (`q`, _) => println("Match!")
    ...
  }
```

Like this:

```
def f(p: Int, q: Int) {
  (p, q) match {
    case (`q`, _) => println("Match!")
    case _ => println("No")
  }
}

f(1, 2)   // "No"
f(1, 1)   // "Match!"
```

Comment: Just `case ('q', _) =>` (swap `'` for backticks) would do... no need to check both `p == q` and `q == p`

Answer (score 7):

You can define your own extractor:

```
object Eq {
   def unapply[T](pair:(T,T)):Option[T] = 
      if (pair._1 == pair._2) Some(pair._1) else None
}
```

Then `(4,4) match { case Eq(n) => println("same: " + n) }` prints `same: 4`, while `(3,4)` wouldn't match.

I listed some comparision extractors in my [blog](http://dgronau.wordpress.com/2011/07/07/eigene-extraktoren/) (sorry, it's in German).

Answer (score 6):

You can swap the values and then compare the tuple with its normal equals-method:

```
scala> val t = (1, 1)
t: (Int, Int) = (1,1)

scala> t.swap == t
res0: Boolean = true

scala> val t = (1, 2)
t: (Int, Int) = (1,2)

scala> t.swap == t
res1: Boolean = false
```